# No visible @interface for 'UIView' declares the selector 'addSubView:'

Tags: objective-c

i am very new to iOS .i am trying to add the UIActivityIndicator in my view controller but it showing the error like  "No visible @interface for 'UIView' declares the selector 'addSubView:'". i added my code for reference.can anyone suggest me how i can rectify this problem

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    spinner.center = CGPointMake([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width/2, [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height/2);
    [_bcview addSubView:spinner];//bcview is the outlet connection for my viewcontroller
}
```

Comment: it's `addSubview:`

Answer (score 6):

The function `addSubview:` is spelled with a lowercased `v`. So you should change `addSubView` to `addSubview`

Generally speaking, you can use Xcode's built in suggestion feature which will suggest functions to you to fix issues like this.

Comment: Please don't answer questions which are clearly off topic and should be deleted.

Comment: Ok, I didn't think it was off-topic. Will keep that in mind, though.

Comment: Generally speaking, i tend to use AppCode instead of the deprecated tool.

Comment: Never heard of that, thanks for the suggestion actually! @YvesLeBorg

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
   [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

    CGSize size = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    [activityIndicator setCenter:CGPointMake(size.width/2, size.height/2)];

    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    [_statusView addSubview:activityIndicator];
}
```

with declaration in .h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *statusView;
```